# how to get first image tag after certain DOM element using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

let's say i have the code like.

```
<h1>Big heading</h1>
<p>small heading</p>
<img src="image.com"/>
.........
```

How do i get the first `img` tag, say after `<h1>` using javascript or jquery?.

Comment: Or, you could supply a little more of your html structure and then we could use the parent as an identifier...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('h1').nextAll('img').first();
```

Happy Coding:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nextUntil()`, and then `next()` to get the next element, which would be the image

```
$('h1').nextUntil('img').last().next()
```

or `nextAll()` and then `first()`

```
$('h1').nextAll('img').first()
```

Comment: [`$('h1').nextUntil('img').next()` will select other elements if there are more than one in between the heading and the img](http://jsfiddle.net/7GyBH/).

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like the first of subsequent image elements after **any** `h1` element, you can use the [next siblings selector (`~`)](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) in conjunction with the [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/):

```
$('h1 ~ img:first')
```

If you'd like the first of subsequent image elements after **every** `h1` element, you'll want to use a more advanced selection:

```
var $imgs = $();
$('h1').each(function () {
    $img = $(this).nextAll('img').first();
    $imgs = $imgs.add($img);
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L9Zfg/)

It's quite a bit more code to do the same search with raw JS, however it's more performant because we can make a number of optimizations that can reduce the number of iterations:

```
function firstImagesAfterHeadings() {
    "use strict";
    var nodeName,
        headings,
        images,
        image,
        ctx,
        i;

    //get all the headings on the page
    headings = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');

    //create a container for the images that are selected
    images = [];

    //iterate through all the headings
    for (i = 0; i < headings.length; i += 1) {
        //start at the heading
        ctx = headings[i];

        //clear out any existing selected images
        image = null;

        //walk through each of the headings' siblings
        //the assignment here is intentional,
        //the second set of parenthesis is used to acknowledge this
        //additionally, the "outer" label is used so that breaking
        //out of the switch also breaks out of the loop
        outer:while ( (ctx = ctx.nextSibling) ) {
            //normalize the node name
            nodeName = ctx.nodeName.toLowerCase();

            switch (nodeName) {
                //the first image found after the heading should
                //be added to the collection
                case 'img':
                    image = ctx;
                    break outer;
                //any headings found after the initial heading should break
                //because they will have been in the headings collection and
                //will be used as a search context on the next iteration of
                // the for loop
                case 'h1':
                    break outer;
            }
        }

        //it's possible that an image is never found,
        //or that a heading is found first
        if (image) {
            images.push(image);
        }
    }
    return images;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jQSkq/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 use the following line to check the img:

  $('h1').nextAll('img:first');
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you can use the pure javaScript like:-

This will provide the first image of first `h1` tag

```
var h1Tag = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
var imgTags = h1Tag.getElementsByTagName('img');
var firstImg = imgTags[0]; //provide the first img after h1 tag
```

Comment: This will find the first image *within* the last `h1` element, it doesn't find the images *after* the `h1` elements.

Comment: @zzzzBov, is this okay now?

Comment: same problem as before, you're searching the descendants of `h1` elements, not finding subsequent siblings.